# How to send a object with a file to WebApi using Angular

Tags: c#, angular, webapi

I'm trying to send a Model to my WebApi Project along with a File but it doesn't work. Because I'm not using the "form" sending. I'm tagging the file at the property. I tried :

1 - `FormData()` formData.append(file);

2 - Creating a Class with the File and the other property

```
export class PR {
filesUpload: File;
PI: Pr;
}
```

and in WebApi

```
 public class ProcessInstanceM
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase filesUpload { get; set; }
    public Pr PI { get; set; }
}
```

The Pr Property comes, but not the file..

Answer (score 0):

According to the MDN there is no version of 'FormData.append()' with 1 argument
There are 2 versions (from MSD page) :

```
There are two versions of this method: a two and a three parameter version:
formData.append(name, value);
formData.append(name, value, filename);
```

I suggest for you to use it like this :

```
formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
```

source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append